# jquery mobile $(html).click( not firing on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

All four of these fire great on my computer

```
$('html').click(function() { alert(1);});
$('body').click(function() { alert(2);});
$('html').on("click", function() { alert(3);});
$('body').on("click", function() { alert(4);});
```

and this fires fine on both

```
$(".nav li").click(function() { alert(5);} );
```

so I'm sure I have jquery and jquery mobile referenced correctly

maybe one of my meta tags kills it?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />  
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="m3t.jpg"/>  
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="m3t.jpg"/>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/mainnav.css">

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jqmobile.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$('body').click` isn't good enough? u specifically need `html`?

Comment: Check the console, do you see any errors?

Comment: Either or would be fine, but I can't get either to work

Comment: no errors on my desktop browser :/  haven't tried debugging through the mobile browser (you can do that on ios right? but you need safari for desktop?)

Comment: off-topic: where is jqm.css? for your issue use `$(document).on('click', '.selector', function()`. Also, specify which versions of jQuery and jQM are you using?

Comment: jqm = 1.3.1; jq = 2.x;  I don't have jqm.css.  I was doing my own css and just using jqm for mobile click events.  Do I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, turned out I had set the z-index in my css that killed it

Thanks for looking